# Choosing adequate Rails session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am currently using a memcached-based session store ( https://github.com/mperham/dalli ). From time to time the memcached server is unavailable ("No server available"), and then my users aren't able anymore to use the application. Currently I have doubts if a memcached-based session is the right decision.

Since I only store very few keys in a session I am thinking about switching back to a cookie store. Or should I consider using an ActiveRecord store? Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: I heard from heroku support, that memcache is having some issues.
But those are resolved. so its still good to go with dalli...specially if you are deploying in heroku.

Comment: If you use cookie store, make sure to not store datas that needs to be marshaled (like dates) or you wouldn't be able to upgrade your ruby version without getting errors during session loading

Comment: So you had similar problems today on heroku? It's my first week running a production app on heroku, that's why I am very unsettled... Does this happen more often on heroku than memcache isn't available?

Comment: According to https://status.heroku.com/ , there were no problems today with the memcached add-on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are storing few keys in the session, I clearly think you should go for a Cookie store.

For that basic need it's easier to maintain.

The guide has some advices on it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: If you have strict security needs, be careful, as cookie store can leave your app open to replay attacks.