# Error when use session_store in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I know session_store has removed from Rails 4.

So I try install it, but have some errors:

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store', plataform: :mri
```

#### Console

Bundle Install

```
C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog>bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.0)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.0)
Using mime-types (1.25)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
Using activemodel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.1)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.0)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.5.1)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.0)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
Using rails (4.0.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass (3.2.10)
Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8)
Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
Using uglifier (2.2.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog>
```

Trying install the gem

```
C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog>rails generate active_record:session_migration
Could not find generator active_record:session_migration.
```

Trying create a session store migration

```
C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog>rails generate active_record:session_migration
Could not find generator active_record:session_migration.

C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog>
```

#### Informations

- Rails 4.0
- Ruby 2.0
- Windows 7 x64 Professional

What's wrong? I follow all the steps of the repository: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

---

## Works!

I re-write the file, and works (I don't know the problem), but I have another problem (**I use proxy**).

```
$ bundle install
Fetching git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error

Git error: command `git clone
"git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git"
"c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d"
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory c:/Sites/rails-estudo-blog has failed.
```

### Solved

I can solve the problem change the url to:

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store', git: 'https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store'
```

So, I change **github** to **git** and put the entire url I want.

#### Thanks!

---

Comment: You did run bundle install ?

Comment: Yes. And I not see `active_record:session_migration` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update with new answer:

After you provided the entire Gemfile, I copied it and tried it directly.  I saw the same problems you had.  So, I retyped the line.  It worked.  I can't say exactly what is wrong within the line, but this works:

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
```

Copy and try it.  If it still fails, delete it and retype it.  The original line was just ignored without any message or reason and the bundle succeeded but missed this gem.  The newly typed line worked.  Go figure.

I left out "plataform: :mri", corrected to "platform: :mri", as it was extraneous.

Be sure to still follow the steps outlined below in my original answer.  They still apply.

Please let me know..

End of update with new answer.  Old answer follows:

I tried this for you, updating Gemfile and running bundle install.  The result added the desired gem, and you can see the initial fetch from git (This was executed with Rubymine, thus the complex command line.):

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\ruby\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) D:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-12/projects/utilities/bin/bundle install
Fetching git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
...
Using activerecord-session_store (0.0.1) from git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git (at master) 
...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Checking the status, I found:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities\app\helpers>bundle show activerecord-session_store
D:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-12/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-022d45b4ae9b
```

Running the generate created the migration:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities>rails generate active_record:session_migration
      create  db/migrate/20131002090526_add_sessions_table.rb
```

The migration is as follows:

```
class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :sessions, :session_id, :unique => true
    add_index :sessions, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Interestingly, gem list didn't show the gem I expected, even though the bundle and generate worked:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities>gem list activerecord-session_store
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities>gem list activerecord-session_store -r
*** REMOTE GEMS ***
activerecord-session_store (0.0.1)
```

But, gem install fixed that:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities>gem install activerecord-session_store
Fetching: activerecord-session_store-0.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-session_store-0.0.1
1 gem installed
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\utilities>gem list activerecord-session_store
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
activerecord-session_store (0.0.1)
```

Recommendations:

1. Run the gem install to make sure you have it installed.
2. Run the gem list to double check.
3. Run bundle update, not bundle install, to build the bundle from scratch.
4. Check the listing to ensure the gem is included as expected.
5. Run the bundle show to double check, again...
6. Run the rails generate to generate the migration.

If the migration fails to run again, check your gem storage for the generator in your gem storage:

```
.../gem/activerecord-session_store-0.0.1/lib/active_record/session_store.rb
```

Comment: Just noticed the question regarding use of Active Record Session Store.  The answer, of course, is it depends upon what you are doing and what you need.  Here is an SO link discussing options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247355/choosing-adequate-rails-session-store

Comment: I'll check your answer today with more calmly evening (I'm at work). After that give you feedback. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Not work. When I execute `bundle install`session_store not has installed. I think bundle is ignoring my gemfile, so i try `--gemfile=Gemfile` and doesn't work too. I not have idea what is wrong.

Comment: Hmmm.  Did you install the gem?  Did you check to make sure the generate code is there?  Did you get the same error?  Is your Gemfile in C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog\Gemfile?  Are you in C:\Sites\rails-estudo-blog when you bundle update?  Please edit your question and include your Gemfile listing if what you provided wasn't the whole thing.  I suggest you create a syntax error in your Gemfile to force bundle to report whether it is reading it.  Are you using an IDE and which one?  Rubymine will retrieve the gem if I need it.  Do you have a "require" in your source for the gem, which may help?

Comment: I not have a "required" for this gem. I use Sublime Text 2, and my question has updated.

Comment: "platform" is misspelled on your gem's line.  Correct that and try it.  Also, I recommend you follow the series of steps I provided.  If you did, explain exactly what failed, when and how.  I'm guessing here because I am not getting all the information.  Thanks.

Comment: Using a direct copy of your Gemfile, with the typo corrected, I am seeing exactly your problem.  Give me a bit to diagnose it for you.

Comment: See the updated answer.  The new answer is at the very beginning so it's easy to find.

Comment: Don't forget to do all the steps I specified in my original answer.  The bundle update DID NOT install the gem with its generators.  I had to perform a gem install to do that.  The steps I outlined will make sure your bundle and your generate work successfully.

Comment: I'll try now your solution, wait a minute.

Comment: Works! I try insert force error in my Gemfile but doesn't work so I create other, and insert everything manually. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Now, I have a problem to download the repository =/ (I'm using proxy)